# How to view stored procedure in zend studio using QuantumDB

Tags: php, zend-framework, db2, zend-studio

How can i view the actual code written inside a procedure using zend studio.

Am using [Quantum DB](http://quantum.sourceforge.net/). I can see the variables used /structure.

I am not able to view the actual code/queries written in procedure

How can i view/ edit the procedure using zend studio.

Any better addon/plugin/extension avaialable ??

Comment: Should this question really be tagged for DB2?

Comment: i put db2 because, i hope guys who look for db2 may notice this question and if they know anything they can answer. no one will search for QuantumDB tag !!

Answer (score 0):

You could query for the text with something like

```
select PROCNAME,TEXT from SYSIBM.SYSPROCEDURES
```

or, you could switch to using [IBM Data Studio](http://www-142.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/data-studio/). It is going to be the default DB2 administration toolkit, and should work better for you.